# Error in git clone of a private repository

Tags: git, github, cmd, git-clone

I'm trying to clone a private repository. I have tried with 2 ways

1. **Using Android Studio**

*Result*
[image]

2. **Using CMD**

*Result*

```
C:\thoughtcast>git clone https://github.com/thoughtcastapp/git.android.ThoughtCast.git
Cloning into 'git.android.ThoughtCast'...
remote: Repository not found.
fatal: repository 'https://github.com/thoughtcastapp/git.android.ThoughtCast.git/' not found
```

**Screenshot to verify the repo**

[image]

> **How do I access my private repository?**

Comment: Can you truly confirm the repository does exist. When i tried to browse to the address i get an error.

Comment: Check the edit... I posted a screenshot of the repo. Btw, it's private, so you can't access it unless you'e me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There can be multiple causes for this error. Try following in the order mentioned

> 1. Include your username in the repo url

```
git clone https://username@github.com/thoughtcastapp/git.android.ThoughtCast.git/
```

> 2. Identify remote git repository to your terminal.

```
git remote set-url origin https://github.com/thoughtcastapp/git.android.ThoughtCast.git/
```

> 3. Uninstall the git credentials manager and reinstall (for cmd, run as administrator)

```
$ sudo git credential-manager uninstall
$ sudo git credential-manager install
```

> 4. If repo has been created by another user, check if you have read-write access.

Comment: Answer updated. Please retry. First one should get the job done :)

Comment: Where can I find if I have read-write access? It's not in Settings.

Comment: When I put the un/pw in... I get this error  Port number ended with 'v'

Comment: special characters in the password cause this problem. I have updated answer to prompt for the password later. I am positive about the first one. Keep me in the loop.

Comment: remote: Repository not found. when I try the updated #1.

Comment: :|. Give #3 a try with `sudo` after #2.

Comment: sudo doesn't exist on windows.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179576/discussion-between-david-kachlon-and-mehtankush).